# Enumerating two collections

Tags: c#

```
class MyClass
{
string identifier;
}
```

I have two lists of identical count

```
List<MyClass> myClassList;
List<string> identifierList;
```

I would like to know what is the best way of assigning identifier in the myClassList enumerating over identifierList?

I wrote this, but looks too long(and inefficient?). There must be a better way of doing this?

```
identifierList.Select((value,index)=>new {value, index}).ToList().ForEach(x=> myClassList[x.index].identifier = x.value);
```

Comment: Why not do a simple `for` loop?

Comment: for loops are past century already. Only LINQ, only hardcore!

Comment: @YacoubMassad Fair point.Just wondering is there any way to do short hand coding efficeiently

Comment: There is always a trade off between using for-loop and LINQ. LINQ does have some overhead compared to for-loop, and the biggest problem is readability. As long as you are comfortable with meaning of that 1 liner and you'll know what it means in 6 months time then it's fine.

Comment: A question though, do you need to have your `myClassList` already instantiated?

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to preserve the ordering? The `Enumerator` for a `List` will preserve the ordering, so you could just simply do: `var myClassList = identifierList.Select(x => new MyClass { identifier = x }).ToList();` and you'll have your list with the same ordering.

Comment: Short code doesn't mean it's faster. A simple for loop would suffice.

Comment: @callum yes, both lists are instantiated and populated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're approach is inefficient(you're creating a throwaway list) and not very readable and also throws an exception if both lists have a different size.

You're looking for the [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx#) extension method which joins by index:

```
var zipped = myClassList.Zip(identifierList, (c, s) => new { class = c, string = s});
foreach(var x in zipped)
    x.class.identifier = x.string;
```

Comment: Would you prefer a for loop above all?

Comment: @Jimmy: no, only if you need to have access to previous or next elements or handle the case that both have a different size. Zip will only process `myClassList.Count` elements from the second collection. Maybe i would prefer a `Dictionary<string,MyClass>`. It's suspicious if you have two collections which are related by index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx#):

```
myClassList.Zip(identifierList, (klass, id) =>
{
  klass.identifier = id;
  return klass
});
```

Note that this will give you a mutating Linq expression.

However, I suspect this is probably clearer:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myClassList.Count; i++)
{
  myClassList[i].identifier = identifierList[i];
}
```

It may not be as "hip" as using Linq, but it's easier to read and understand what's going on!

Comment: LINQ queries are not supposed to cause side effects ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I know :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about simple query like this.

```
myClassList.Select((e, i) => { e.identifier = identifierList[i]; return e; }).ToList();
```

We need this `.ToList()` to execute the query, otherwise it'll just do nothing.

Example :

```
        List<string> identifierList = new List<string>()
        {
            "abc", "def", "ghi"
        };

        List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>()
        {
            new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass(),
        };

        myClassList.Select((e, i) => { e.Id = identifierList[i]; return e; }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in myClassList)
            Console.Write(item.Id + "  ");
```

Output : `abc  def  ghi`

In case your collections are of different length you can use :

```
myClassList.Select((e, i) => { e.Id = i < identifierList.Count? identifierList[i] : e.Id; return e; }).ToList();
```